# Actions after a Grapple

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, balance, grapple

I'm playing a Goliath Barbarian, focusing on the inherent grappling advantages. I'm trying to pull as much benefit from Powerful Build as possible. My specific questions are:

1. Considering my Goliath can lift over 2000 pounds, can I just lift an enemy above my head?
2. If I can lift this enemy, does it require a second grapple check to do so, or can I just do it if I still have him grappled when I attempt it?
3. Since I am eight foot tall and holding this enemy above my head with my long arms likely extending to at least 10 feet, will the enemy being dropped cause 1d6 fall damage?
4. Is my movement impaired while moving with a grappled enemy that I have lifted from the ground, or is it not since I'm below my carrying capacity of 1000 pounds?
5. If my movement is impaired, could I just throw this person as an improvised weapon up to 20-60 feet? Could I throw this individual vertically for 6d6 damage?
6. Could I actually use this person as an improvised weapon? If I could, would his similarity to a weapon be a greatclub for 1d8 damage? If I swung this improvised weapon at a person, would it deal 1d8 damage to both people or just the person being hit? Could I also throw this person at someone else for 1d8 plus 1d6 for coming from a height above 10 feet (overhead toss)?

This is where RAW tears severely against logic/reality. I could eventually see myself having a lifting capacity of **5 tons** through enlarge + enhance ability, but not be able to toss a halfling across the battlefield.

Comment: One question per question please, or at least a set of tightly linked questions.  These are all pretty different.  And it's unclear whether those are really questions, or whether they are rhetorical questions just setting up your last statement making your question "the raw is goofy right?" which isn't a good question.

Comment: Second that ^^ please separate these. Perhaps into one about lifting (your bolded paragraphs 1, 2, 4), one about improvised person-weapons (5a, 6), maybe one about dropping? (Also, in 5a why does it matter if your movement's impaired?)

Comment: Also, can you explain tagging it both with [tag:rules-as-written] and [tag:house-rules]?

Comment: And how did you establish that your character has a lifting capacity of (or over) 2,000 pounds? Lifting capacity is 30 times Strength, doubled for Powerful Build. Strength can't be higher than 20, and 60 x 20 = 1,200. (The "5 tons" number (10,000 pounds) is even more of a stretch).

Comment: If you break this down into six separate questions, I'd love to answer them all.